# How do I ignore cell references that contain text when performing calculations?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010

For instance I am trying to use a very simple formula, like so:

```
=(B1+C1+D1+E1)/4
```

Now let's say that cells B1 & D1 contains the numbers 201, 301 respectively. Let's say that cells C1 & E 1 contain the text "-". Now when I attempt to run the calculation I'm given the following error:

```
#VALUE
```

How can have the formula ignore the text and only perform calculations on the cells that contain numbers?

Comment: Excellent. Add the answer so that I can give you credit. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
=SUM(B1:E1)/4
```

instead.

Though different formulae may need different approaches. For example, sometimes is may be better to arrange that `"-"` is displayed via special formatting for values that are actually `0`.  (So the *appearance* is of text but the value is actually numeric.)

In other cases wrapping a formula that derives a result used elsewhere in [IFERROR](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx) may be appropriate.

Use of [SUMPRODUCT](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/), an [array formula](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx) or conditionals such as [SUMIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-function-HP010062465.aspx) and [COUNTIF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx) (and their 'big brothers' SUMIFS/COUNTIFS) may be more suitable - in effect by preselecting only the values that would not give rise to such errors.